# I can't stop a simple service

Tags: android, service, destroy

I know that this question has already been asked, but the solutions I find do not solve the problem, at least for me.

I have a simple service that I call at a certain time from an activity. This service executes an action every three seconds.
The service works well, but after reading a lot about the subject and trying all the solutions I find, I can't destroy the service and stop it. the onStartCommand method always runs again and I start over.

Can someone tell me the changes I have to make in my code to stop the service completely and destroy it?

I insist, **stopSelf(), stopService(), etc, etc ... At no time has the service stopped**

Thank you very much and I leave my code:

```
public class myService extends Service {

  //...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (mTimer != null) {

        } else {
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }

        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.e(TAG,"Service onDestroy");

    }

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    vuelta  = vuelta +1;

                    if (vuelta==2){

                        stopSelf();

                    } else {
                        // NA
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Service onDestroy" prints to logcat, then your `Service` has indeed stopped. That does not mean that your `Timer` has stopped.

The Android framework has no way of knowing what threads are associated with your `Service`, so it does not take the liberty of killing any particular thread when it decides to destroy your `Service`. This is true even if the `Service` object itself is GC'd. (As implemented, though, your `myService` object will not be GC'd, because there are several references to it via the `Timer` thread and the `TimeDisplayTimerTask` within that `Timer`.)

You may find that the `Timer` stops running eventually, some minutes after you had commanded the `Service` to stop; this is likely because Android has terminated your app entirely, in order to free up resources for higher priority apps, and/or the "foreground" app.

To improve the situation, you should `purge()` your `Timer` in `onDestroy()`.